# Stack pointer add on loop

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention, stack-pointer

Learning some reverse engineering and I came across some examples of loops in x86 assembly

```
00401036        mov     [ebp+var_4], 0
0040103D        mov     [ebp+var_8], 0
00401044 loc_401044:
00401044        cmp     [ebp+var_4], 0
00401048        jnz     short loc_401063 
0040104A        call    performAction
0040104F        mov     [ebp+var_8], eax
00401052        mov     eax, [ebp+var_8]
00401055        push    eax
00401056        call    checkResult
0040105B        add     esp, 4
0040105E        mov     [ebp+var_4], eax
00401061        jmp     short loc_401044
```

From my understanding, esp is the stack pointer so:
Why is 4 being added to the stack? It would make sense if this was a recursive call but it’s just a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely using C calling convention, which is "caller cleans up". This convention allows for variable-argument functions like printf where the callee does not know how many arguments are on the stack.

The whole bit you should look at is:

```
00401055        push    eax // argument for checkResult
00401056        call    checkResult
0040105B        add     esp, 4 // clean up the argument
```

the `add` could have been a `pop eax`, except the code is not interested in the value, so it just moves the stack pointer.

Comment: If the `add esp, 4` were to be replaced by `pop eax`, precaution would be in order so as to move the `mov [ebp+var_4], eax` instruction one line up (before the `pop eax`)

Comment: yeah, eax is probably a bad example, because C typically uses it for return value, so imagine some other register (and then the value you don't actually care about would clobber that register...)

Comment: For the record, other calling conventions exist, like MSVC's stdcall and fastcall, which are "callee pops"; the `checkResults` function would use `ret 4` instead of `ret` to clear the args as it returned.  But "caller pops" conventions are also widespread (e.g. i386 System V, and cdecl on Windows, and all mainstream x86-64 calling conventions.)

Comment: really appreciate the timely answer from @teapot418 and further elaboration from everyone else!